# WebBrowser control or similar functionality with MVC4 razor

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a small proof of concept to load a third party site such as facebook etc and post login credentials to it using WebBrowser Control in a windows app.
Little bit of code snippet is as follows:

```
 WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
 w.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 this.Controls.Add(w);
 w.Navigate(@"https://....");

 var inputs = w.Document.Window.Frames[1].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

  foreach (HtmlElement element in inputs)
  {
      var name = element.GetAttribute("name");

      if (name.ToUpper().Contains("USERNAME"))
      {
          element.SetAttribute("value", email);                   
      }
  }
```

Now idea is to create a web page and do the same thing and I am using MVC4 razor specifically. I found an article suggesting how to use a WebBrowser control in ASP.net application [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET).
I am gonna try this article now but I really want to know if there are other(better) alternatives to achieve this functionality specifically in MVC4 razor.

Comment: the idea makes little sense.  what possible reason could there be for this?

Comment: @Dan-o Client requirements. I have set of username and passwords. I provide a link to my user when user clicks on it I should fetch his credentials and post them to a third party site. Cant get the requirements changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Selenium a shot, it has C# bindings

http://docs.seleniumhq.org

If you are trying to do this in the end user's browser this would not be the solution for you, since this would run server side. In that case that would probably involve some iframe magic or other types of fun

Comment: I am by no means a cross site scripting expert but you are probably going to encounter a lot of issues doing this on the end user side since browsers are designed to not allow much interaction between different domains. Perhaps someone else can provide more insight.